# Because of search_tmp page is loading very slow magento2

Tags: magento2

I am loading product collection in custom page. It is taking almost 26 seconds to load the page. I have 4.5 million records and the number of products per page is  only 30. Also there is no layered navigation. 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: Is the magento cache enabled ?

Comment: yes. cache and page cache.

Comment: its in developer mode,but search result page is loading 4 to 5 seconds only

Comment: Can you post your code and xml files here. If possible , take a backup of your DB and try using flat catalog instead of EAV. Are you facing this problem in your local machine also ?

Comment: i have flat catalog enabled. i have magemojo server.problem with search_tmp insert